# firebase hasChildren working in simulator but not angularFire

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning firebase I have the following simple rule set up:

```
{
   "rules": {
       ".read": "auth != null",
        "messages": {
        ".read": "true",
        "$conversation_id": {
            ".write": "newData.hasChildren(['receiver_id','sender_id','timestamp'])"
        }
    }
    }
}
```

in the simulator the write rule passes with:

```
{
 "receiver_id":123,
 "sender_id":"test",
 "timestamp":123
}
```

Using angularFire i get permission denied (uid is defined):

```
var dat = {
         sender_id:uid,
         receiver_id: uid,
         timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

 };
  database.ref('messages/myMessageId').push(dat);
```

if i remove the hasChildren check the message gets added to the database with the proper values populated. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Firebase.push()` automatically creates a new unique id (similar to an array index), so the structure you should let AngularFire take care of this for you by using `database.ref('messages').push(dat)`

```
// will fail because /myMessageId does not contain child sender_id
database.ref('messages/myMessageId').push(dat);
{
  messages: {
    myMessageId: {
      UID: {
        sender_id: 1,
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}


// will work
database.ref('messages').push(dat);
{
  messages: {
    UID: {
      sender_id: 1,
      ...
    }
  }
}
```